# Is it acceptable to insert Participe Passé into the expression "se trouver + dans/sur/etc"?

Tags: usage

In conversation with my colleague, I said:

> Comment tu fais pour enlever efficacement les poussières qui ***se trouvent accumulées sur*** la surface du clavier ?

When I use the reflexive "se trouver" in the sense of "se situer", I usually have a preposition immediately follow "se trouver":

> Comment tu fais pour enlever efficacement les poussières qui ***se trouvent sur*** la surface du clavier ?

But I spontaneously thought of adding the idea of "accumulées" into the sentence somehow, leading to this turn of phrase: "se trouvent accumulées sur". I wonder if this construction is acceptable too?

Comment: Incidentally, is there a better phrase than "sur la surface du clavier"? After all, I intended it to mean " hard-to-reach spots between keys where  dust easily settles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Qui se trouvent accumulées* is correct French, but is slightly formal so I probably won't use it with a colleague. I would say instead (colloquial spoken French):

> *Tu fais comment pour enlever<sup>1</sup> les saletés<sup>2</sup> coincées<sup>3</sup> entre les touches du clavier ?*

1 or *faire partir*
2 or *cochonneries*
3 or *collées*

Answer (score 0):

Le participe passé à ici valeur d'adjectif, « qui se trouvent accumulées  sur le clavier » peut être remplacé par « qui se trouvent belles sur le clavier » (ce n'est pas le meilleur exemple pour illustrer la chose mais bon). Mais j'utiliserais plutôt « les poussières accumulées sur le clavier », ça paraît plus naturel.